# PgBouncer cannot connect to server

Tags: windows, errors, postgresql-9.6, pgbouncer

I have configured PgBouncer with PostgreSQL 9.6 on windows 7 machine. Here are the pgbouncer configuration settings;

```
[databases]

test = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=master_db user=postgres password=test123

[pgbouncer]

logfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\log\pgbouncer.log
pidfile = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\log\pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
auth_type = md5
auth_file = C:\Program Files (x86)\PgBouncer\etc\userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = postgres
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

user list file

```
"test_user" "bacha"
```

When i try to connect to a database using pgbouncer, through this command;

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6432 -U test_user master_db
```

i get this error

```
psql: ERROR:  client_login_timeout (server down)
psql: ERROR:  pgbouncer cannot connect to server
```

How can i solve this **Problem** ?